# Как получить отдельные параметры из ответа сервера vk-api

Tags: php, json, laravel

При работе с VK API получаю ответ:

```
{"response":{"type":"user","object_id":506019729}}
```

Как получить с этой строки с помощью PHP параметры `type`, `object_id`?

Сейчас использую такой костыль, какие есть еще решения?

```
$out = explode('{"response":{"type":"group","object_id":', $out);

if (isset($out[1])) {
    $id = $out[1];
    $id = trim($id, "}"); 
    Log::alert("ID: ".$id);
} else {
    $id = null;
}

return $id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы принимаете ответ в JSON и работать с ним нужно как с JSON.

```
$result = json_decode($response); // stdClass
```

или

```
$result = json_decode($response, true); // array
```

У вас получится готовый к работе массив параметров, который дальше можно перебирать через foreach и производить все необходимые действия.

Ваш код, если хотите работать с ответом как с **stdClass**:

```
$result = json_decode( '{"response":{"type":"user","object_id":506019729}}' );
echo $result->response->type;
// выведет user.
```

Ваш код, если хотите работать с ответом как с **array**:

```
$result = json_decode( '{"response":{"type":"user","object_id":506019729}}', true );
echo $result["response"]["type"];
// тоже выведет user.
```

Пример работы с API vk в одном из моих проектов.

```
$result = json_decode( vk_query( 'https://api.vk.com/method/board.getComments', array(
    'lang'             => $lang,
    'group_id'         => $group_id,
    'topic_id'         => $topic_id,
    'need_likes'       => $need_likes,
    'start_comment_id' => $start_comment_id,
    'offset'           => $offset,
    'count'            => $count,
    'sort'             => $sort,
    'extended'         => $extended,
    'access_token'     => $access_token,
    'v'                => $v
) ), true ); // делаем запрос к VK с нужными параметрами и декодируем ответ в массив
/* ... код запроса к БД через PDO */
foreach ( $result['response']['items'] as $item ) { / перебираем массив ответа ВК

    if ( $post_id < $item["id"] && $item["text"] != "" ) {
        // биндим нужные параметры для записи в БД
        $query->bindParam( ':post_id', $item["id"] );
        $query->bindParam( ':from_id', abs( $item["from_id"] ) );
        $query->bindParam( ':date', $item["date"] );
        $query->bindParam( ':text', $item["text"] );

        $query->execute(); // записываем в БД нужные значения
    }

}
```